# Title missing from a recent response

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-replies

One of my recent responses in Stack Overflow includes a comment that just says "**commented on**" with no question title, and there is no link to the question, so I can't click on it to see where it's coming from.

This seems like a bug. (is it a deleted question?)

The particular comment is by Idigas and the comment is "@S.Lott - nice one.", but I have no idea which question so I can't link to it for you.

Comment: Here's the answer it was posted on (found by going to ldigas' recent activity page): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471313/do-i-always-have-to-think-about-performance/471327#471327

Comment: to whoever "-1"'d this question: would you care to comment why? not like I care about rep on meta-SO, but if you feel like throwing stones for a legitimate question, please don't do so anonymously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main /users/recent query was recently tuned like a Ferrari and it makes an assumption that answers have null titles.  Your reported bug exposed a much older time in our code where somehow answer titles could have empty strings (which is no longer the case).

We're fixing the data, which will fix this issue - thanks for finding it!

Comment: It looks fixed for my particular answer. thanks!